# How can I permanently remove hyperlinks to other spreadsheets in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a huge spreadsheet, after some copying and pasting from other documents I see the warning that there is a hyperlink to another spreadsheet on every time i open the file. While this does no damage, I want my collegues to work with the thing without seeing an error message every time the open the tool.

Now, when i choose data -> edit links (or similiar, I'm working on a german version excel) I see one link to another file, I choose "delete link" and nothing happens. Meaning: The link is still displayed, I still get the warning. I try to make the external source point to the actual file I'm working on, I get an error message that the link does not work.

I want to work on the cell directly that conains the offending link, how can I find it? The spreadsheet is large and contains many sheets. Is there a tool or function that can help me here?

Any other ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Do a Find.
2. Search for `:\` (assuming your link will point to a mapped drive, eg C:\. If it's pointing to a location on a server try searching for `\\` instead)
3. Set to search `within` the entire workbook.
4. Then click `Find All`.
5. Scan down the list in the `Formula` column of the results section for any offending links.
6. Use the `Replace` functionality to alter the links as required.

[image: find all links]

Comment: I did, the search (for both variants) shows nothing - while 'data' -> 'links' shows a link to 'C:\ ...' what can this be?

Comment: Ah, I see. You must have a hyperlink attached to a cell rather than linked within a formula. Have a read of this and see if running this VBA helps: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/859-excel-list-hyperlinks.html

Comment: I did, the list generated by the macro is empty (only the column headers, no error messages).

Comment: OK, try looking in your Formula Name Manager (on the `Formulas` tab). You may have a named reference to an external file. Also check if you have any hidden worksheets.

Comment: Did both things, no success. By now I'm really puzzled. But with the name mnager I found lots references to external files (that are unreachable) that do not generate the warning that started the whole thing. curios and curioser.

Comment: Sounds like your workbook is full of little niggly problems! I think if it was me I'd copy and paste formulas & formats for each worksheet into a brand new workbook.

Answer (score 0):

When copying/pasting between Excel Workbooks, Excel copies more than just the cell data. It copies anything and everything associated with the data. This includes Font styles, cell formatting, formulas, data validation rules, conditional formatting rules, hyperlinks, even network location. This "feature" causes mysterious/unexpected behaviors, especially when multiple users are involved.

To answer this question, [this web page](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/find-remove-external-links-from-excel-spreadsheet) details various ways to find and remove external links.